# How to call loadView() from an xcode framework properly

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, swift2

```
override public func loadView() {
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("DatePickerDialog", owner: self, options: nil)
}
```

This code is the usual way of linking a ViewController to its interface builder. However, once I moved these kinds of files to a framework, and make a call to it, it crashes. I know that I can override an init and specify the bundle ID but it won't pre-load the UI and will result from UI elements not initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `NSBundle.mainBundle()`, call either `NSBundle(identifier: String)` or `NSBundle(forClass: AnyClass)`. The former takes an NSString argument of the framework's indentifier; the latter takes a Class argument of a class provided by the framework.

Comment: thanks, @Abhinav! `NSBundle(identifier: String)` and `NSBundle(forClass: AnyClass)` are the current syntax. Anyway, the idea is what's important, so thank you very much!

Comment: I just changed it. Thanks for pointing out. It was a typo in a rush :)

Comment: It's the thought that counts :D